# Image in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: image, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have form for upload file and i want to upload thumbnail for the file in the same form I am doing that with this part of code :

```
var basePath2 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Thumbnails\\");
bool basePathExists2 = System.IO.Directory.Exists(basePath2);

if (!basePathExists2) 
     Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath2);

var thumbnailPath = Path.Combine(basePath2, Thumbnail.FileName);

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(thumbnailPath))
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(thumbnailPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await Thumbnail.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

I am saving this model to the database:

```
var fileModel = new FileUploadViewModel
                    {
                        Year = createdOn,
                        PublishedOn = model.PublishedOn,
                        FileType = File.ContentType,
                        Extension = extension,
                        Name = model.Name,
                        Description = model.Description,
                        FilePath = filePath,
                        Author = model.Author,
                        ThumbnailPath = thumbnailPath,
                    };
```

When I want to show the thumbnail in a view, it doesn't work but in `src` I have the right path, as you can see in this screenshot:

[Screenshot with Source of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI43W.png)

Comment: Can you expand on "It doesn't work"?

Comment: *"but in src i have the right path"* - The `src` value in the image you're showing is a file system path, not a URL.  That's **almost certainly** not "the right path".  What's the **URL** for the image in your web application?

Comment: The src url has something called "Unnamed" (unless that's right?), also as @david says, that's a file system path.

Comment: i understand you,whats the easiest way to make url from file system path ?

Comment: @DevGary: That depends on how your application serves that image.  Is it a static resource available from within the website folder?  Is it served dynamically by streaming through a controller action?  Something else?

Answer (score -1):

In controller :

```
string uniqueThumbName = null;
            if (Thumbnail != null)
            {
              string uploadsFolder =  Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Thumbnails");
                uniqueThumbName=Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Thumbnail.FileName;
                string filePath2 = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueThumbName);
                Thumbnail.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath2, FileMode.Create));
            }


var fileModel = new FileUploadViewModel
                    {
                        ThumbnailPath=uniqueThumbName,
                        };
```

In View :

```
var thumbPath = "~/Thumbnails/" + file.ThumbnailPath;

    <img style="width:80px;height:80px;" src="@thumbPath" asp-append-version="true" />
```